# Code not running after while loop in Java

Tags: java

I've got the most random problem. Simply put I look to iterate in a while loop until a certain condition is met and when its not met obviously the code after the loop should be run. For some reason the code after the while loop doesn't run... Here is my code:

```
while (true) 
        {
            Socket ClientSocketConnection = serverSocket.accept();
            System.err.println("We have established a connection with a client!");
            System.out.println(" ");

            ServerInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocketConnection.getInputStream()));
            ServerOutput = new DataOutputStream(ClientSocketConnection.getOutputStream());

            while((StringInput = ServerInput.read()) != -1)
            {
              //Things get done here

            }

            //methodBeingUsed is a string here

            switch (methodBeingUsed){
                case "GET":
                    GET();
                    break;
                case "POST":
                    POST(sBuffer.toString());
                    break;
            }

            System.err.println("The Connection will now Terminated!");
            ServerOutput.close();
            ServerInput.close();
            ClientSocketConnection.close();
        }
    }
```

Basically the switch statement isn't being run for some reason?? When I debugged the code I get to the last -1 from the `ServerInput` variable the code just stops. Stops and doesn't continue with everything else in the `while(true)` loop. Really not sure why this is happening...

Comment: What is `MethodBeingUsed`? What are the possible values it can have?

Comment: Oh sorry its just a String Variable

Comment: @user12345 : Where you able to get any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously blocking method : `ServerInput.read()`, it means, that it waits until it actually reads something. If it does not read anything it is just waiting. You are probably not connected properly to the existining connection.

Comment: Touche you are correct I thought at the end of the line of my data being read then a -1 would be used to show no more data is left and end the loop. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea of I can modify the code to kick out of the loop once the last bit of data has been read from the ServerInput variable?

Comment: I havent used Socket class for years... try to google "java non-blocking Socket read" and you can do it with it. Or something like "hasInput" boolean method should exists.